# How To Use Laravel Sentiment Analysis?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I already installed likely https://github.com/AntoineAugusti/laravel-sentiment-analysis and i don't know how to use this syntax, because i'm new user used laravel. How to place the code to controller, routes, and .blade?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Put more details of the issue that you are facing. Include the relevant code snippets you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the installation instruction given in repo: [Laravel Sentiment Analysis
: Installation](https://github.com/AntoineAugusti/laravel-sentiment-analysis#installation)

How to use:

```
use SentimentAnalysis;

$sentiment = new SentimentAnalysis();

// returns true or false
$sentiment->isPositive('your sentence string here');



// returns string: 'positive', 'neutral', 'negative'
$sentiment->decision('your sentence string here');
```

You can check more examples in test implementation in [SentimentAnalysisTest.php](https://github.com/AntoineAugusti/laravel-sentiment-analysis/blob/master/tests/LaravelSentimentAnalysis/SentimentAnalysisTest.php)